# I'm trying to make 2 things fade in, one when one link is selected, the other when the other link is selected?

Tags: jquery, fadein

Right, I have 4 divs, I want 1 and 3 to fade in when a link is clicked, and 2 and 4 to fade in when the other button is clicked. I'm using JQuery. Here's what I've got so far:

```
<div id="video selector" style="float: right; width: 250px; background-color:#f3f3f3; height: 210px; margin-bottom:13px;">
<a href="#">
  <script>
     $(document.body).click(function () { 
         $("#1").fadeIn("slow"); 
         $("#3").fadeIn("slow"); 
         $("#2").hide();  
         $("#4").hide();
      });
  </script>
  <img src="img/electronic recycling play.png" style="width:220px; padding-left:15px; padding-top:12px; padding-bottom:9px; cursor:pointer;" />
  </a>
  <center>Electronic Recycling</font></center>
  </div>
```

This one is loading divs 1 and 3.

```
<div id="video selector2" style="float: right; width: 250px; background-color:#f3f3f3; height: 210px;">
 <a href="#">
   <script>
         $(document.body).click(function () { 
            $("#2").fadeIn("slow"); 
            $("#4").fadeIn("slow"); 
            $("#1").hide();  
            $("#3").hide();
         });
    </script>
    <img src="img/battery recycling play.png" style="width:220px; padding-left:15px; padding-top:12px; padding-bottom:9px; cursor:pointer;" />
    </a><center>Battery Recycling</font></center>
  </div>
```

This one is loading divs 2 and 4.

The problem is they both load the same divs (2 and 4), and the video doesn't switch, just reloads the same one, wither button you press... any ideas?

Comment: Welcome to the site! You may want to format your code so it is easier to read (rather than just one long line). You're more likely to get help more quickly that way. Thanks!

Comment: IF this is supposed to happen when you click the button why are you using `document.body` as your selector?

Comment: I don't see any HTML to support the jQuery you have shown. Also, it is illegal to start an ID with a number, it should always begin with a letter. Please show the supporting HTML, including the links you are clicking as well as the DIVs you are trying to show/hide.

Comment: I'm new to both this forum and the JQuery & HTML world, sorry!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Add an id to your a tag like this:

```
  <a href="#" id="firstlink"> ... </a>
```

Then in the document ready function add the click event handler like this:

```
  <script>
 $(document).ready(function () {
     $("#firstlink").click(function(){ 
     $("#1").fadeIn("slow"); 
     $("#3").fadeIn("slow"); 
     $("#2").hide();  
     $("#4").hide();
   });
  });
</script>
```

The above code can go in the head of your page rather than in the content of the a tag. It adds the event handler such that when the a tag with id firstlink is clicked it executes the function. A similar function can be done for the next link.

Comment: should be `#firstlink` for that selector.